# On the convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be an increasing sequence of positive real numbers tending to $\infty$. Then
$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n - a_{n - 1}}{a_n^\sigma}$ converges for any $\sigma >1$.

Colud anybody tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: When $\sigma \geq 2$, it is easy to see. But I don't know why it is true for the case $1 < \sigma < 2$.

Comment: I know what to do now. Just use Lagrange Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Please share the approach you found.

Comment: From $\frac{a_n - a_{n - 1}}{a_n^\sigma}\leq\frac{a_n - a_{n - 1}}{a_n^\sigma - a_{n - 1}^\sigma}$, the result follows easily.

Comment: You mean, you are able to show "easily" that the series $$\sum\limits_n \frac{a_n - a_{n - 1}}{a_n^\sigma-a_{n-1}^\sigma}$$ converges? I doubt that, but anyway you should include these explanations in your question.

Comment: By Lagrange Mean Value Theorem, $\frac{1}{\sigma - 1}(\frac{1}{a_{n-1}^{\sigma - 1}}-\frac{1}{a_n^{\sigma - 1}}) = \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{\xi_n^{\sigma}}\geq\frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{a_n^\sigma}$. Now the result follows.

Comment: Sorry about the comment two days ago. I figured out it several months ago, so I couldn't remember what it exactly goes on.

Comment: Funny, this is equivalent to the bound my answer proves (without Lagrange MVT) and makes use of to show the result. And now what?

Comment: Of course they are equivalent. The difference is that you use integral cleverly and I use MVT. That is why I didn't put my answer there when I saw yours. But later you wanted me to share, so I wrote it rashly, that is what happened. What do you mean by "now what"? Thanks for all your help, OK?

Comment: You are welcome. The appreciation shows.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n\geqslant1$,
$$\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{a_n^\sigma}=\int_{a_{n-1}}^{a_n}\frac{\mathrm dx}{a_n^\sigma}\leqslant\int_{a_{n-1}}^{a_n}\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^\sigma},$$
hence
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{a_n^\sigma}\leqslant\int_{a_0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^\sigma},$$
and the RHS is finite for every $\sigma\gt1$, thus, the series with nonnegative terms on the LHS converges.

Note that the result holds for every nondecreasing positive sequence $(a_n)$, not necessarily increasing and not necessarily unbounded.